# Which is more appropriate to use .count() or .agg(F.sum('count')).collect()[0][0]?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, query-optimization, databricks

I am working in MS Azure with Databricks, writing in Python while I query my data and wondering if it is more efficient or appropriate to use one of the following for obtaining total counts of events in a spark df.

Either like this:

```
df_count = (
  df_main
  .select('name', 'id', 'point_of_origin')
  .where(col('point_of_origin') == 'option_1')
  .distinct()
  .groupby(
  .agg(F.sum('count')).collect()[0][0] 
)
```

OR, like this:

```
df_count = (
      df_main
      .select('name', 'id', 'point_of_origin')
      .where(col('point_of_origin') == 'option_1')
      .distinct()
      .count()
    )
```

NOTE: I get the same values for each option, but the first option is slightly faster, although the speed varies based on the load on the cluster in any given run.

Comment: In the zen of python, it states that `simple is better than complex` so maybe the second option?

Answer (score 0):

`.collect()` will retrieve all chunks of `df_main` from all nodes to the driver node. It will be faster in small dataframes because the data will not be spread around but if the dataframe is higher than the driver memory, you will propably experiment an `OutOfMemory` error.